# How to concatenate strings, integers and floating point numbers without using objects?

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, type-conversion, concatenation

I'd like to add information in a crash dump file, in case my application crashes.

Therefore I've created a `__try`-`__except` clause:

```
__try
{
  Do_Something();
}
__except (ShowCrashdumpInformation(_T(__FUNCTION__));
```

Instead of just `__FUNCTION__`, I'd like to add more information, but how can I do that?

The simpliest way is to use a `CString`, but this is blocked because of compiler error `C2712` (Cannot use __try in functions that require object unwinding).

So, I'd like to use `LPCTSTR` strings (which are widely used in my application).

As a result it should look like (`CString` alternative):

```
CString temp; temp.Format(_T("Do_Something, int=[%d], float=[%f], string=[%s]), iParam, fParam, strParam);
```

Do anybody have an idea?
Thanks

Comment: `__try` is not standard. Probably a compiler extension. You need to specify the compiler you use and why do you use these instead of the standard `try catch`

Comment: @bolov it's structured exception handling, MSVC extension to catch Windows exceptions (e.g. DivisionByZero). try/catch wouldn't catch those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the easiest solution is to simply sidestep the problem. Just forward the exact arguments, not converted, to a (template) function which does the actual writing to file. Since the `__catch` is not in the template function itself, but one level up the stack, you're safe.

Comment: The function `ShowCrashdumpInformation()` indeed writes a string to an external file, and it uses a `LPCTSTR` as input. Currently this is filled in with `__FUNCTION__`, but I'd like to add more to it, hence my question. (For your information, I have such structure on more than 300 places in my code, and I'm looking for adding more information in this particular case)

Comment: @Dominique: So you add a `template<typename... T> void YourClass::ShowMoreCrashdumpInformation(LPCWSTR fun, T... args)` in between, for that particular case.

Answer (score 2):

You could use preprocessor macros to "stringify" the standard `__LINE__` macro, and rely on the compiler adjacent string-literal concatenation.

Perhaps something like this:

```
#define STRx(x) #x
#define STR(x) STRx(x)

#define FILE_FUNCTION_LINE (__FILE__ ":" __FUNCTION__ ":" STR(__LINE__))

...

ShowCrashdumpInformation(_T(FILE_FUNCTION_LINE))
```

As long as you have literal values, you could use the `STR` macro to "stringify" them and then use adjacent string concatenation.

It's not possible using variables though, only using literal values.